# Apache Solr dynamic fields not retrievable

Tags: dynamic, solr, field

I have just begun with Apache Solr dynamic fields.
Here are my query and schema definition:

Query in data-config.xml

```
<entity name="PREPARE"
        query="SELECT tk1_consume,tk1_remain,tk2_consume,tk2_remain
        from test_table">
</entity>
```

Schema.xml

```
   <dynamicField name="*_remain"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
   <dynamicField name="*_consume" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I deleted all other dynamicField
However, when I query all in Solr admin, I've found that there are no information of dynamic fields shown in result.
So I wonder what's wrong with my configuration for dynamic fields?

Comment: did you mentioned the tk1_consume and other tk1 as fields in data-config?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Where you're indexing the information to the fields in `data-config.xml`?

Comment: I config them all in schema.xml (or managed-schema.xml). In Schema Browser, I already see *_remain and *_consume in the dynamic field section.

Comment: Could anybody help me :( ?